# Conflict routes and params name in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my website, users can visit category via `example.com/category1`, `example.com/category2`, etc. So I write the route rule as below:

`match '/:category' => 'home#category', :constraints => ShowCategory.new`

ShowCategory is a Class that make sure the category user visited is exist. At the same time, users can specify their personal domain name, then his/her profile page can be visited via url like `example.com/peter`. So There is another route rule:

`match '/:user_domain' => 'Profiles#show'`

Because I use the `:constraints` for category route, the routes didn't conflict. However, in the `Profiles#show` action I always get the parameters `{'category' => 'peter'}`, not `{'user_domain' => 'peter'}`.

How can I correct the parameter name? I don't want a parameter named `category` in the profiles controller.

Thanks.

Comment: Showing the relevant code, **your `ShowCategory` class**, would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way you're naming your routes doesn't make much sense; it's making the routing engine confused. It should be `categories/1` rather than `category1`.

As for the profiles, I guess the first rule and the `to_param` method should be enough.

```rb
# routes.rb
profile '/:user_domain', controller: 'profiles', action: 'show'
resources :profiles
resources :categories
```

```rb
# profile.rb
def to_param
    self.user_domain
end
```